# How can I deduce the existence of $2^X$ from the powerset axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The below exercise and the axiom to which it pertains can be found in Tao's *Analysis I*, which I am currently self studying.

> **Axiom 3.11** (Power set Axiom) For any two sets $X$ and $Y$, there exists a set, denoted $Y^X$, which consists of all functions from $X$ to $Y$. Thus, 
>   $$f\in Y^X \ \iff \ (f \ \text{is a function such that} \ f:X\to Y).$$
>   **Exercise 3.4.6** Show that the above axiom implies the existence of the set
>   $$2^X:=\{S\mid S\subseteq X\},$$
>   which consists of all subsets of a set $X$. (Hint: start with the set $\{0,1\}^X$ and apply the [replacement axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Statement), replacing each function $f$ with the object $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.

As the author suggested, we start with the set 
$$\{0,1\}^X = \{f\mid f:X\to\{0,1\}\},$$
and replace its elements with subsets of $X$. Clearly, this procedure yields the set $2^X$ however, I am unsure how I can apply the axiom of replacement. How can I do this bit? Any *hints* or *tips* are greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** This question has been [asked and answered elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649895/exercise-from-taos-analysis-book-proof-of-a-lemma-relating-to-power-set-of-x?rq=1), I have just found.

Comment: Think of the `characteristic function` of a subset.

Comment: @Bernard $f$ maps elements of $X$ to zero or one (indicating whether some $x\in X$ in some subset $S$), thus the set $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ consists of those elements who are in $S$.

Comment: Therefore, $\{0,1\}^X$  is in bijection with $\mathscr{P}(X)$.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, okay. So the axiom of replacement need not even be applied?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm no specialist of axiomatic set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the powerset axiom, $Q:=\{0,1\}^X$ exists, but its elements are functions $X\to\{0,1\} $ and not subsets of $X$.

We thus replace them to the appropriate subsets, using the replacement axiom with a formula $\phi(y, z) $ that expresses that $y$ as a function maps exactly the elements of $z$ to $1$. 
$\phi$ needs to satisfy $\phi(y, z_1)=\phi(y, z_2)\ \to\ z_1=z_2$ and then by replacement, we obtain $P(X) =\{z:\exists y\, (y\in Q\land\phi(y, z)) \} $.

Comment: Could you be more explicit as to how one can apply the axiom of replacement?