# Prove that the set of all subsets of a set is itself a set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Problem from Tao's Analysis I.

*Exercise* 3.4.6. Prove Lemma 3.4.10. (Hint: start with the set $\{0,1\}^X$ and apply the replacement axiom, replacing each function $f$ with the object $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.)

I have read some answers on stackexchange ([(exercise from Tao's analysis book) Proof of a lemma relating to power set of X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649895/exercise-from-taos-analysis-book-proof-of-a-lemma-relating-to-power-set-of-x) , [Finding a correspondence between $\{0,1\}^A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84180/finding-a-correspondence-between-0-1-a-and-mathcal-pa)) but my proof is a little different and I want to know if it's correct and complete, using the provided axioms.

> **Lemma 3.4.10** Let $X$ be a set. Then the set $\{Y: Y \textit{ is a subset of } X \}$ is a set.
>
> **Axiom 3.7** (Replacement). Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x\in A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x,y)$
>   pertaining to $x$ and $y$, such that for each $x \in A$ there at most
>   one $y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true. Then there exists a set
>   $\{y:P(x,y)\textit{ is true for some }x\in A\}$, such that for any
>   object $z$, $$z\in\{y:P(x,y)\textit{ is true for some }x\in A\}\\ \iff
> > P(x,z) \textit{ is true for some } x\in A$$
>
> **Axiom 3.11** (Power set axiom). Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted $Y^X$, which consits of all the functions from
>   $X$ to $Y$, thus $$f\in Y^X \iff \textit{ ($f$ is a function with
>  domain $X$ and range $Y$).}$$

*proof*. By Axiom 3.11, $\{0,1\}^X$ is a set, namely, 
$$\{0,1\}^X=\{f: \textit{ $f$ is a function from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$}\}.$$
Then by Axiom 3.7, 
$$\{A:A=f^{-1}(\{1\} \textit{ for some } f\in \{0,1\}\}\text{  is a set.}$$
We will show that for all sets $A$, $A\in P$ if and only if $A\subseteq X$.

Let $A\subseteq X$, and let $I_A:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be the function such that
$$I_A(a)=\begin{cases}
0 \text{, if } a\notin A \\
1 \text{, if } a\in A
\end{cases}.$$
Since $I_A$ is a function from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$, $I_A\in \{0,1\}^X$. We will show that $A=I_A^{-1}(\{1\})$.
Suppose $a\in A$. Then $I_A(a)=1$, hence $a\in I_A^{-1}(\{1\})$. Now suppose $a\in I_A^{-1}(\{1\})$. Then $I_A(a)\in\{1\}$, hence $I_A(a)=1$, so $a\in A$.

Thus $A\in P$ if and only if $A\subseteq X$, thus $P$ is the set of all subsets of $X$.